# SharePoint modal dialog, inner styling

Tags: sharepoint-foundation

I have designed my custom master page. Now, that master page also apply in SharePoint modal dialogs.

I want to change certain css for that popup only. Is their any way I can do that? I have triedt o change css on `ms-dlgframe` load event. But it's not working.

```
function Hide() {
        $('.ms-dlgFrame').load(function () {
            try {
                $('.s4-pr.s4-ribbonrowhidetitle', frames[0].document).hide();
                $('.s4-pr.s4-ribbonrowhidetitle', frames[1].document).hide();
                $('.wrapper').css("min-width", "0");

            } catch (e) {

            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To change CSS styling on the modal dialog, you need to use the something like this:

```
.ms-dialog .wrapper
{
  min-width: 0;
}
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you are using SharePoint 2010 in some form or other: There is the CSS class `s4-notdlg` - Assign this class to all master page elements that you do not want to appear in the modal dialogs.

For more information refer to http://blog.drisgill.com/2009/11/sp2010-branding-tip-2-custom-master.html

Comment: Thanks for replay. I have done similar that. But my problem is that i have to change wrapper class css when it open in model dialog box. How can i change that? For all page wrapper class css is fine but when i open in model popup i have to change css

Comment: I don't think the wrapper class approach is a good idea, and I don't know why you ask me about it. I did not recommend it for the very reasons you are now experiencing. The s4-notdlg is a robust approach.